# >10sec aggregation performance in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and have recently setup a flow of storing JMX data polled every 10seconds into an elasticearch index that looks like this:

```
{
  "jmxmetrics": {
    "mappings": {
      "kafkajmx": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "attr_type": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "host": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "kafka_broker_id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "kafka_clientId": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "kafka_fetcher_id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "kafka_metric_group": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "kafka_metric_name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "kafka_metric_type": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "kafka_topic": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "metric_path": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "metric_value_number": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "metric_value_string": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "path": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "topic_partition": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm then using a web portal built in ReactJs to hit the API endpoints in elastic search so that I can populate things like: `hosts` in a drop down, or `topics` in that host that was selected.

For example, if I run this query:

```
POST /jmxmetrics/kafkajmx/_search
{

                "size": 0,
                "aggs" : {
                  "topics": {
                     "filter": { 
                        "range": {
                           "@timestamp": {
                              "from": "now-60s"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "aggs": {
                        "topics":{
                           "terms": {
                              "field": "kafka_topic",
                              "size": 500
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
                },  
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "host": "host_A"
                    }
                }
}
```

it takes about 25seconds to return:

```
{
  "took": 24709,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1053380207,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "topics": {
      "doc_count": 54915,
      "topics": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 189,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 45098,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "__consumer_offsets",
            "doc_count": 503
          },
          {
            "key": "topic 1",
            "doc_count": 196
          },
          {
            "key": "topic 2",
            "doc_count": 193
          },
          {
            "key": "topic 3",
            "doc_count": 142
          }, 
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any elasticsearch aggregation query seems to take 10+ seconds to run, and my cluster topology looks like this (running on AWS Ec2):

3 master/data nodes c4.2xlarge (8 cores, and 15Gb ram)
1 client node t2.large (2 cores, 8gb ram)

Any idea on what I could be improving here? I know this is a fairly broad question but any pointers will be helpful.

-------EDIT--------

Here are my settings:

```
{
  "jmxmetrics": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1489771989403",
        "number_of_shards": "3",
        "number_of_replicas": "2",
        "uuid": "DeLP9MrQT6S_kILMmXorew",
        "version": {
          "created": "5020199"
        },
        "provided_name": "sdpjmx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

also, here are my stats:

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 9,
    "successful": 9,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_all": {
    "primaries": {
      "docs": {
        "count": 1402484967,
        "deleted": 0
      },
      "store": {
        "size_in_bytes": 261239372859,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "indexing": {
        "index_total": 1402487151,
        "index_time_in_millis": 108231827,
        "index_current": 0,
        "index_failed": 0,
        "delete_total": 0,
        "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
        "delete_current": 0,
        "noop_update_total": 0,
        "is_throttled": false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "get": {
        "total": 1,
        "time_in_millis": 13,
        "exists_total": 0,
        "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
        "missing_total": 1,
        "missing_time_in_millis": 13,
        "current": 0
      },
      "search": {
        "open_contexts": 0,
        "query_total": 692,
        "query_time_in_millis": 1390846,
        "query_current": 0,
        "fetch_total": 76,
        "fetch_time_in_millis": 15444,
        "fetch_current": 0,
        "scroll_total": 0,
        "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
        "scroll_current": 0,
        "suggest_total": 0,
        "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
        "suggest_current": 0
      },
      "merges": {
        "current": 4,
        "current_docs": 57546764,
        "current_size_in_bytes": 10961768409,
        "total": 359830,
        "total_time_in_millis": 298632418,
        "total_docs": 8639051262,
        "total_size_in_bytes": 1733171768674,
        "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 208268389,
        "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 15728640
      },
      "refresh": {
        "total": 2290338,
        "total_time_in_millis": 27698495,
        "listeners": 0
      },
      "flush": {
        "total": 1398,
        "total_time_in_millis": 512144
      },
      "warmer": {
        "current": 0,
        "total": 2291685,
        "total_time_in_millis": 365893
      },
      "query_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 131229184,
        "total_count": 13019,
        "hit_count": 905,
        "miss_count": 12114,
        "cache_size": 118,
        "cache_count": 139,
        "evictions": 21
      },
      "fielddata": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "completion": {
        "size_in_bytes": 0
      },
      "segments": {
        "count": 167,
        "memory_in_bytes": 868415719,
        "terms_memory_in_bytes": 731359089,
        "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 125593776,
        "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "norms_memory_in_bytes": 32064,
        "points_memory_in_bytes": 11138810,
        "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 291980,
        "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 9788964,
        "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 290304,
        "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
        "file_sizes": {}
      },
      "translog": {
        "operations": 529724,
        "size_in_bytes": 275528684
      },
      "request_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0,
        "hit_count": 0,
        "miss_count": 84
      },
      "recovery": {
        "current_as_source": 0,
        "current_as_target": 0,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      }
    },
    "total": {
      "docs": {
        "count": 4207454779,
        "deleted": 0
      },
      "store": {
        "size_in_bytes": 776849456528,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "indexing": {
        "index_total": 4207461365,
        "index_time_in_millis": 333522565,
        "index_current": 0,
        "index_failed": 0,
        "delete_total": 0,
        "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
        "delete_current": 0,
        "noop_update_total": 0,
        "is_throttled": false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "get": {
        "total": 2,
        "time_in_millis": 13,
        "exists_total": 0,
        "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
        "missing_total": 2,
        "missing_time_in_millis": 13,
        "current": 0
      },
      "search": {
        "open_contexts": 0,
        "query_total": 2046,
        "query_time_in_millis": 4439867,
        "query_current": 0,
        "fetch_total": 204,
        "fetch_time_in_millis": 61910,
        "fetch_current": 0,
        "scroll_total": 0,
        "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
        "scroll_current": 0,
        "suggest_total": 0,
        "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
        "suggest_current": 0
      },
      "merges": {
        "current": 9,
        "current_docs": 90922106,
        "current_size_in_bytes": 17436129588,
        "total": 993305,
        "total_time_in_millis": 889392309,
        "total_docs": 25596362951,
        "total_size_in_bytes": 5109527514241,
        "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 622031369,
        "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 47185920
      },
      "refresh": {
        "total": 6870703,
        "total_time_in_millis": 80442220,
        "listeners": 0
      },
      "flush": {
        "total": 4194,
        "total_time_in_millis": 1542414
      },
      "warmer": {
        "current": 0,
        "total": 6874724,
        "total_time_in_millis": 1048456
      },
      "query_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 428618904,
        "total_count": 38315,
        "hit_count": 3196,
        "miss_count": 35119,
        "cache_size": 371,
        "cache_count": 438,
        "evictions": 67
      },
      "fielddata": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "completion": {
        "size_in_bytes": 0
      },
      "segments": {
        "count": 492,
        "memory_in_bytes": 2604314152,
        "terms_memory_in_bytes": 2194198429,
        "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 375756256,
        "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "norms_memory_in_bytes": 94464,
        "points_memory_in_bytes": 33422427,
        "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 842576,
        "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 22793264,
        "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 853888,
        "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
        "file_sizes": {}
      },
      "translog": {
        "operations": 1591047,
        "size_in_bytes": 827579505
      },
      "request_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0,
        "hit_count": 0,
        "miss_count": 345
      },
      "recovery": {
        "current_as_source": 0,
        "current_as_target": 0,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "indices": {
    "jmxmetrics": {
      "primaries": {
        "docs": {
          "count": 1402484967,
          "deleted": 0
        },
        "store": {
          "size_in_bytes": 261239372859,
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "indexing": {
          "index_total": 1402487151,
          "index_time_in_millis": 108231827,
          "index_current": 0,
          "index_failed": 0,
          "delete_total": 0,
          "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
          "delete_current": 0,
          "noop_update_total": 0,
          "is_throttled": false,
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "get": {
          "total": 1,
          "time_in_millis": 13,
          "exists_total": 0,
          "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
          "missing_total": 1,
          "missing_time_in_millis": 13,
          "current": 0
        },
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 692,
          "query_time_in_millis": 1390846,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 76,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 15444,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        },
        "merges": {
          "current": 4,
          "current_docs": 57546764,
          "current_size_in_bytes": 10961768409,
          "total": 359830,
          "total_time_in_millis": 298632418,
          "total_docs": 8639051262,
          "total_size_in_bytes": 1733171768674,
          "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
          "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 208268389,
          "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 15728640
        },
        "refresh": {
          "total": 2290338,
          "total_time_in_millis": 27698495,
          "listeners": 0
        },
        "flush": {
          "total": 1398,
          "total_time_in_millis": 512144
        },
        "warmer": {
          "current": 0,
          "total": 2291685,
          "total_time_in_millis": 365893
        },
        "query_cache": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 131229184,
          "total_count": 13019,
          "hit_count": 905,
          "miss_count": 12114,
          "cache_size": 118,
          "cache_count": 139,
          "evictions": 21
        },
        "fielddata": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "evictions": 0
        },
        "completion": {
          "size_in_bytes": 0
        },
        "segments": {
          "count": 167,
          "memory_in_bytes": 868415719,
          "terms_memory_in_bytes": 731359089,
          "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 125593776,
          "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
          "norms_memory_in_bytes": 32064,
          "points_memory_in_bytes": 11138810,
          "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 291980,
          "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 9788964,
          "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 290304,
          "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
          "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
          "file_sizes": {}
        },
        "translog": {
          "operations": 529724,
          "size_in_bytes": 275528684
        },
        "request_cache": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "evictions": 0,
          "hit_count": 0,
          "miss_count": 84
        },
        "recovery": {
          "current_as_source": 0,
          "current_as_target": 0,
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "docs": {
          "count": 4207454779,
          "deleted": 0
        },
        "store": {
          "size_in_bytes": 776849456528,
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "indexing": {
          "index_total": 4207461365,
          "index_time_in_millis": 333522565,
          "index_current": 0,
          "index_failed": 0,
          "delete_total": 0,
          "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
          "delete_current": 0,
          "noop_update_total": 0,
          "is_throttled": false,
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "get": {
          "total": 2,
          "time_in_millis": 13,
          "exists_total": 0,
          "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
          "missing_total": 2,
          "missing_time_in_millis": 13,
          "current": 0
        },
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 2046,
          "query_time_in_millis": 4439867,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 204,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 61910,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        },
        "merges": {
          "current": 9,
          "current_docs": 90922106,
          "current_size_in_bytes": 17436129588,
          "total": 993305,
          "total_time_in_millis": 889392309,
          "total_docs": 25596362951,
          "total_size_in_bytes": 5109527514241,
          "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
          "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 622031369,
          "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 47185920
        },
        "refresh": {
          "total": 6870703,
          "total_time_in_millis": 80442220,
          "listeners": 0
        },
        "flush": {
          "total": 4194,
          "total_time_in_millis": 1542414
        },
        "warmer": {
          "current": 0,
          "total": 6874724,
          "total_time_in_millis": 1048456
        },
        "query_cache": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 428618904,
          "total_count": 38315,
          "hit_count": 3196,
          "miss_count": 35119,
          "cache_size": 371,
          "cache_count": 438,
          "evictions": 67
        },
        "fielddata": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "evictions": 0
        },
        "completion": {
          "size_in_bytes": 0
        },
        "segments": {
          "count": 492,
          "memory_in_bytes": 2604314152,
          "terms_memory_in_bytes": 2194198429,
          "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 375756256,
          "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
          "norms_memory_in_bytes": 94464,
          "points_memory_in_bytes": 33422427,
          "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 842576,
          "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 22793264,
          "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 853888,
          "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
          "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
          "file_sizes": {}
        },
        "translog": {
          "operations": 1591047,
          "size_in_bytes": 827579505
        },
        "request_cache": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "evictions": 0,
          "hit_count": 0,
          "miss_count": 345
        },
        "recovery": {
          "current_as_source": 0,
          "current_as_target": 0,
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are your settings?

Comment: I just made an edit to include my `_stats` and `_settings`.

Comment: If you are sending the query to the client node, then I suggest testing the same query by sending it to a data node instead. Your client node might be too small.